# getting exception .NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/log/CounterFactory

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfa

I am trying to create a PDF/A document using itext and java with the following code:

```
PdfAWrite writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(myDoc, myStream, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
```

but I keep getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/log/CounterFactory
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter.<init>(PdfAWriter.java:210)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter.getInstance(PdfAWriter.java:86)
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

can anyone tell what should I do to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get similiar exceptions when I have the said class in more than one jar.  Maybe you should check your classpath for duplicates.  Maybe different versions of the same library coexist.  If you're using Eclipse, have a look at the 'Dependency hierarchy' view of the pom and try to locate a duplicate.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion. The `NoClassDefFoundError` is often misleading in the sense that more than one version of the class if found, but the exact class can't be defined, because it's ambiguous: which version should be used? In any case: solving this should be a no-brainer. Plenty of people are using iText without experiencing this problem. Starting from scratch can always help.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie as you say the NoClassDefFoundError is misleading, the problem was that I had multiple dependecies in my pom.xml files. I solved the problem thanks to Kenneth's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you miss the `itextpdf.jar` in your classpath. Download the jar and add it to your classpath

Comment: I have that itextpdf-5.5.3.jar in my classpath along with the itext-pdfa-5.5.3.jar

Comment: @Shahe Can you show the classpath configuration? You are runing your app from IDE?

Comment: I am running my application from Eclipse IDE, and I am building my project with maven.

Comment: I am sorry, can you be more exact on what do you want me to show you? I don't know where the run configuration is.

Comment: @Shahe If you run your program from eclipse you use a launcher. You can see it under "Run"-->"Run Configurations". There you have a tab classpath. An the content of this should contain the jar as one entry.

Comment: OK.. I don't see the jar file in the classpath. I added the jar and it worked, but what if I want to run the application NOT from eclipse, what should I do then?

Comment: You have also add it to your classpath. If you have added it as dependency to your pom.xml maven should manage that for you.

Comment: that is the EXACT problem, maven is not doing that for me... I updated my question, please check my pom.xml

Comment: What kind of application is it? A Web application or what?

Comment: Yes, it is a web application, jsf/hibernate/maven

Answer (score 0):

The current release of Primefaces libraries refers to an older release of iText. If you try to install the latest iText distribution you will end up to the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/`

This is due to the fact that in the recent iText release the package `com/lowagie/text` has been renamed as `com/itextpdf/text`. So until this is fixed use the suggested iText release (2.1.7) or at least verify the package structure.

This might be useful:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/primefaces/export-your-datatable-to-excel-and-pdf-using-primefaces?showall=&start=1